# Exporting website information

Tags: vbscript

I am fairly new to VBScript. I would like to extract price information from a website (i.e. overstock.com). If I search an item in the search box for example item number 11111696. How can I get its price exported out to an excel sheet by using VBScript?
For example, I have this code in VBScript that uses IE to go that site, look for that product by item number.

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "www.overstock.com"
wscript.sleep(2000)
    IE.document.all.item("search-input").value = 11111696
wscript.sleep(300)
    IE.document.all.item("search-button").click
```

Comment: I edited Question, if it makes it to qualify to ask. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using VBScript?

Comment: That's all I know. End purpose is to get the price and in-stock information of the product from given website and spit it out in excel. Process is repetitive for many items.

Comment: I am open to any suggestion and only need to perform these repetitive tasks:
1. go to website
2. read item by item number from excel
3. check the price by running above script
4. check in-stock status and max number of quantities available in drop down.
5. Append above info in separate excel sheet.
6. repeat for other Item number